# Selenium headless browser webdriver [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, httplib, centos6.5

I am trying to scrape data from the URLs below. But selenium fails when `driver.get(url)` Some times the error is `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`, sometimes `[Errno 111] Connection refused`. **On rare days it works just fine** and on my mac with real browser the same spider works fine every single time. So this isn't related to my `spider`.

Have tried many solutions like waiting got selectors on page, implicit wait, using selenium-requests yo pass proper request headers, etc. But nothing seems to work.

```
http://www.snapdeal.com/offers/deal-of-the-day
https://paytm.com/shop/g/paytm-home/exclusive-discount-deals
```

I am using `python`, `selenium` & `headless Firefox webdriver` to achieve this. The os is `centos 6.5`.

*Note:* I have many `AJAX` heavy pages that gets scraped successfully some are below.

```
http://www.infibeam.com/deal-of-the-day.html, http://www.amazon.in/gp/goldbox/ref=nav_topnav_deals
```

Already spent many days trying to debug the issue with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After days of jingling around this issue, finally found the cause. Writing it here for the benefit of the community. The headless browser was failing due to lack of `RAM` on the server, strange error messages from `webdriver` were real `pita`.

The server was running straight up for `60` days without reboot, Rebooting it did  the trick. After increasing the swap by 3 times, has not faced issue for past few days. Also scheduled a task to cleanup page file caches (http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html).

Answer (score 7):

I have been using Selenium and chromedriver (python3) for scraping purposes for some time now. With the latest Google Chrome update I had to deal with two issues.

1) **Error on webdriver launch:**

Solution: I had to add "no-sandbox" argument.

chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

2) **[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer:**

Solution. There seems to be a problem with sockets and http requests. Either the webpage content is too big or you don't give the page enough time to load. At least that's what I thought.
I set the maximum page load time to 60 seconds and it seems to be working fine.

driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)

I added a small delay between webdrivers initialisations which also seems to help.

time.sleep(0.5)

Comment: did you mean "--no-sandbox"? or should it be without two preceding hyphens?

Answer (score 7):

Found this question while looking for similar error. 
Look's like it's a selenium 3.8.1 and 3.9.0 bug.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5296

Downgrade to 3.8.0 solves this problem

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it's working once downgraded. Hope it will behave the same :)