# Selenium headless ChromeDriver fails with ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have a Python (3.5) script that uses Selenium (3.12), chromedriver (2.39) and Google Chrome (67) on a headless Debian (9) server.

The Python is installed in a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

About 50% of the time the script runs without fault. The other 50% I get the following errors. Is this just a plain ol' bug in chrome/chromedriver (both latest versions direct from Google) or is it likely anything to do with my setup/code?

### My code is pretty standard:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()                                                                                                                                                                        
options.add_argument('headless')                                                                                                                                                                           
options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
options.add_argument('window-size={}x{}'.format(*self.window_size))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

### Error message:

```
  File "./grab-regulars.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "cwd/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "cwd/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "cwd/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "cwd/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "cwd/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "cwd/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 496, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1198, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Try to downgrade to 3.8

Comment: Thanks, downgrade to 3.8.0 seems to have worked. <https://stackoverflow.com/a/48983008/623519>

Answer (score 2):

As you are on **Debian Server** and working with ***Headless Chrome*** you need to configure the *WebDriver* instance as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized') 
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('window-size={}x{}'.format(*self.window_size))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
```

Reference

- [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)
- [trouble running chrome headless browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581940/trouble-running-chrome-headless-browser/49582534#49582534)

Comment: Thanks, I've added all those arguments but am still getting a 50% chance of it working.

Comment: Thanks. Working for me.